# Wordpress theme - My footer doesn't stay at the bottom

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, web

I'm having a huge issue with my custom Wordpress theme. 
I've done a lot of research but it doesn't seem to get fixed.
My footer does not stay in the bottom of the page, it even floats mid page in posts and statics pages.
I've tried everything out there but nothing seems to work. I've also noticed that this is very common problem that can have many causes so I don't really know what's going on here. I've checked and re-checked my code but I don't know where's the error.
Also, my footer has a huge blank space above it in the homepage, I've tried applying bottom and top margins but nothing works.

I attached the code and some screenshots!
Please help me, thank you very much!

http://www.screencast.com/t/1uTrUy6t26z
http://screencast.com/t/ASOXPY0G

```css
body{
    font-family: DINCond;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper{
    
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1180px;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

h1.banner{
    background-image: url(images/nuevo-banner_01.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}

header nav{
    float:right;
}

header nav h2{
    text-indent: -10000px;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


header nav li{
    float: left;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 10px;
    position:relative;
        top: -398px;
    left: -287px; 
}

header nav li a{
    
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #baa383;
    font-size: 18px;
}

#section-menu ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#first-column{
    
    position: relative;
    top: -23px;
    left: -50px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 30px;
}

#first-column li{
    
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    width: 100%
}

#second-column{
    
    position: relative;
    right: -320px;
    top: -533px
        
}

#second-column li{
    
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
    width: 100%;
}

#third-column li{
    
    position: relative;
    right: -730px;
    top: -1034px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 -65px;
    width: 100%;
}

#banner-inferior{
    
    position: relative;
    top: -1030px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    
}


footer{
    
  width:100%;
 height: 100px; 
 position:absolute; 
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
    display: block;
}

#redes{
    
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    top: -35px;
    
}

#redes li{
     display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
   position: relative;
    left: 50px;
}

h3.redes{
    
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
}

.comment-meta{
    
    position: relative;
}

footer ul{
    
    list-style-type: none !important;
    font-size: 25px;
    float: right;
    
}

footer li{
    
    text-align: center !important;
}

#post-content{
    
    float:left;
    width: 70%;
    clear: both;
}

#sidebar{
    
    float:right;
    width: 26%;
    padding: 1%;
    background: #ffffff;
}

#sidebar li{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: -40px;
    position: relative;
    left: -20px;
}


.comment-list{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head> 
    <title>Aprende A</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    
<body>
    
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            
            <h1 class="banner">Aprende A</h1>
            <nav>
             <h2>Main Navigation</h2>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Productividad</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Finanzas Personales</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Salud</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Otros</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
                 
            </nav>
        
        </div> 
        
    </header>
    
    <!--Start of homepage content-->
    
    <div class="wrapper">
       <section id="section-menu">
           
           <section id="first-column">
           <ul>
           <li><a href=""><img src="images/images/baner-frase-inferior_04.jpg"></a></li>
           <li><a href=""><img src="images/newsletter.jpg"></a></li>
           </ul>
           </section>
           
           <section id="second-column">
           <ul>
           <li><a href=""><img src="images/images/categorias_06.jpg"></a></li>
           <li><a href=""><img src="images/images/novedades_15.jpg"></a></li>
           </ul>
           </section>
           
            <section id="third-column">
           <ul>
           <li><a href=""><img src="images/images/populares_09.jpg"></a></li>
           </ul>
           </section>
           
           <section id="banner-inferior">
               
            <img src="images/images/populares_19.jpg">
           
           </section>
        
        </section>
    </div>
    
    <!--End of homepage content-->
    
    <footer>
    
        <div class="wrapper">
            
           <div id="redes">
               <ul>
            <li>Síguenos en nuestras redes sociales</li>
            <li><a href=""><img src="images/instagram.png"></a></li>
               <li><a href=""><img src="images/facebook.png"></a>a></li>
            </ul>
                   </div>
            <ul>
            <li><img src="images/library.png"></li>
            <li>Aprendiendo A</li>
            <li>&copy; All rights reserved 2016</li>
            </ul>
                       
        </div>
        
    </footer>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: any chance you can share your site? The code provided, when run, is sticking to the bottom.

Comment: Hello Eliezer! This is the website http://aprendiendo-a.com thank you very much for checking it out and trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I am looking into your code now but there is an issue with an anchor tag for your facebook.png that shows

```
<a>a> //take a> away
```

Comment: I think you have improper syntax for your css I will create a footer that you can manipulate in a moment.

Comment: Hello Anthony! Thabk you for that observation but I don't think that affecting the footer :( I'm still getting the same problem. I'll be waiting for that footer your creating, I'm sure it'll be helpful :) thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The CSS code of your footer is position:absolute. You should use position absolute only if you know what you are doing.

Look at your code:

```
footer {
    width:100%;
    height: 100px; 
    position:absolute; 
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    display: block;
}
```

You can read this as zero pixels away from bottom, zero pixels away from left, but in absolute position. As soon as you scroll the page the footer will go with the scroll this is what you in 99.999% of the cases do not want for a footer. It is also responsible for the blank space on your frontpage.

Try instead:

```
footer {
   position:fixed;
}
```

... if you want the footer to stick to the bottom but always be visible or try

```
footer {
       position:inherit;
    }
```

... for the usual behaviour.

Read more about the position property here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

By the way: Please recognize that a question like this is not very likely to be well answered as you posted a lot of unessecary code (read more on how to create [a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Hello Blackbam! Thank you for that great explanation and your help. I tried that but know the footer moves when I scroll up and down.
I've tried everything but nothing works.

Comment: Try position:inherit or position:relative. This is probably what you want? And remove bottom:0; and left:0; its probably not what you want ...